# SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws

I need help with calling a web service. 
I use `org.springframework.ws.client` to call WS, code looks like:

```
Response response = (Response) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                "http://ip:port/DefaultRequestListener?workflow=WsdlCPF&soapAction=Import",
                request,
                new SoapActionCallback("http://ip:port/DefaultRequestListener?workflow=WsdlCPF&soapAction=Import"));
```

Also I can call WS and receive response using this link `http://ip:port/DefaultRequestListener?workflow=WsdlCPF&soapAction=Import` (it looks strange) using SOAP UP. It works fine.

After run code from IDE I receive next stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:677)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at com.mayacomp.feeder.Application.main(Application.java:33)
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at com.mayacomp.feeder.Client.createApplication(ExternalChannelClient.java:133)
    at com.mayacomp.feeder.Application.lambda$0(Application.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:674)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:188)
    ... 13 more
```

So the root problem is:
`Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?`

Could you recommend some workarounds to solve this problem?
I am ready to get any additional info if need.

**UPDATE**
As I understood the problem is in the next things:

In the request sent by client I have:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacom/Generic/Ws">
```

but should have:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://mayacom/Generic/Ws">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ws:request>
```

How do I set it up?

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.mayacomp.feeder.Client");
    return marshaller;
}


@Bean
public ExternalChannelClient externalChannelClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    ExternalChannelClient client = new ExternalChannelClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("http://ip:port/DefaultRequestListener?workflow=WsdlCPF&soapAction=Import");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your service returns wrong `Content-Type` HTTP header.

See you stack trace:

```
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611)
```

That means response parsing, and `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType` would like to deal only with `type=text/xml` or `type=application/soap+xml`.

Comment: Can i somehow to let client works with content type: text/html in response?

Comment: Also i checked response in wireshare. Really there was `content-type: text/html` and information about exception like `<faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">General exception before validation step: java.lang.Exception: Error: No Root element in response!</faultstring>`.

Comment: I can't anderstand it, but when i sent soap request from Soap UI it works fine.

Comment: @Artem Bilan what was the solution, as i have same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830582/invalid-content-typetext-html-soap-client

Answer (score 2):

**Probable solutions to this problem**

1) Check if your jars are present at given location or classpath

2) Your endpoint URL must be valid.

In my case there is an additional forward slash(/) in url

**Example**
incorrect - http://localhost:8088//mockService (which is causing above issue)

correct   - http://localhost:8088/mockService (check if it is working using Postman)